# Get binary data with XMLHttpRequest in a Firefox extension with AXIOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-saga

I am trying to download binary data from Firefox browser. My app is based on react and redux and using axios as my HTTP client. 
I have to send 
  `xhr.open()` before `responseType= arraybuffer`

Below implementation didnt work

```
 axios({
        url:`http://api.demo6.test.com:8080/resources/v1/${dObj.payload.surveyId}`,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        method: 'post',
        data: dObj.payload.filterData,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Bazaarify-Session-Token": "cfff-7-07f13399abed" //token
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        // const y  = yield put(surveyResponseDowloadComplete({
        //     data: response.data
        // }));
        let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "test.xls";
        link.click();
        console.log(response);
        //response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('ada_lovelace.jpg'))
    });
```

How can I do it with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple saga that downloads binary data using axios:

```
function * downloadFileSaga(url) {
    const response = yield axios.get(url, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    })
    console.log(response.data); // arraybuffer
}
```

You can then use Blob or FileReader to work with the arraybuffer further.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n7kmvjr49m

Comment: thanks @martin the solution provided by you didn't work

Comment: Seeing the code in your updated question I suspect the problem isn't the code itself but probably some network permissions. I have unfortunately no experience with FF extensions, but in e.g. Chrome you have to set the right access rights in the extensino manifest file.